# Migration from source safe 2005 to tfs 2010

Tags: team-foundation-server

I cannot find Vssconverter.exe in the visual studio 2008 but i found it in visual studio 2010 can i use it to migrade a solution in vs 2008 from source safe 2005 to tfs

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Visual Studio version. If anything, it might have to do with the TFS version. Yes, the VS2010 version of the tool is fine to use with a VS2008 project (or with text files, or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Team Explorer 2010, the VSS Converter.exe tool should be available in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE folder.